# Intellij Live Template with Mockito

Tags: intellij-idea, mockito

So I'm trying to create a live template in Intellij for Mockito. What I have is follows:

`$VAR$ = Mockito.mock($VARCLASSNAME$);$END$`

VAR has the expression of suggesteFirstVariableName()

Now what do I need to put in for the expression so that it automatically picks up the class name of the VAR?

Thanks,

Comment: What game are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I have:

```
$CLASSNAME$ $VAR$ = Mockito.mock($CLASSNAME$.class);$END$
```

**Expressions**

```
 - CLASSNAME:
 - VAR: decapitalize(CLASSNAME)
```

So, I just need to type the name of the class I want to mock once, and all the rest is automatically completed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: great! I'd modify it a bit for field declaration by adding 'private final' => private final $CLASSNAME$ $VAR$ = Mockito.mock($CLASSNAME$.class);$END$